# join collection to get the customer name (for admin grid)

Tags: magento

I have a table for my custom module with following columns:

```
---------------
| custom_table|
---------------
| id
| seller_id
| buyer_id
| ...
---------------

seller_id -> customer_enity [entity_id]
buyer_id -> customer_entity [entity_id]
```

Now i would like to show the seller name and buyer name in admin grid layout.
I couldn’t figure out how to retrieve the seller name and buyer name from the customer entities.
But i know how to retrieve their emails as:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
  $collection = Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommodule')->getCollection();  
  $collection->getSelect()
        ->join( array('ce1' => 'customer_entity'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.seller_id', array('seller_email' => 'email'))
        ->join( array('ce2' => 'customer_entity'), 'ce2.entity_id=main_table.buyer_id', array('buyer_email' => 'email'));
  #echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

This above code works fine. But i want to display their names instead of email.
Can any body help me to modify this collection?

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to join with customer_entity_varchar table where the name is store,
and the attribute_id = 5, 5 because it is the id of the attribute name in the table eav_attribute where all attributes are store
hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get first and last name of customer

```
    $this->_infoCollection = Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommodule')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('ce2.attribute_id', array('eq' => array(5)))
    ->addFieldToFilter('ce3.attribute_id', array('eq' => array(7)));  

    $this->_infoCollection->getSelect()
    ->join( array('ce1' => 'customer_entity'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('customer_email' => 'email'))
    ->join( array('ce2' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce2.entity_id=ce1.entity_id', array('customer_first_name' => 'value'))
    ->join( array('ce3' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce3.entity_id=ce1.entity_id', array('customer_last_name' => 'value'));
```